# mySQL duplicate foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm a beginner at MySQL and I'm trying to set up a database for personal use.
I am trying to give multiple 'Werknemer' the same 'Jobfunctie'.

For example:
A member of the crew (werknemer) (0100) is an 'arbeider'.
A 2nd member of the crew (werknemer) (0101) is also an 'arbeider'.

```
CREATE TABLE Werknemer (
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    voornaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    achternaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    adres varchar(30) not NULL,
    telefoon varchar(10) not NULL,
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    primary key(personeelsnummer),
    foreign key(winkelnummer) references Winkel(winkelnummer)

CREATE TABLE Jobfunctie (
    jobfunctie varchar(15) not NULL,
    salaris_in_euro int(10) not NULL,
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    foreign key(personeelsnummer) references Werknemer(personeelsnummer),
    primary key(jobfunctie)
);

INSERT INTO Werknemer values
(0100, 'firstname', 'lastname', 'adress', 'telephone', 0001);
INSERT INTO Werknemer values
(0101, 'firstname2', 'lastname2', 'adress', 'telephone', 0002);

INSERT INTO Jobfunctie values
('Arbeider', 1500, 0100);
INSERT INTO Jobfunctie values
('Arbeider', 1500, 0101);
```

This means that 'Arbeider' shows up twice as primary key which is impossible. How can I assign multiple people to the same job?

Comment: Add an identifier to the `Jobfunctie` table and set that as primary key and add an identifier that links to the `Jobfunctie` table in the `Werknemer` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook solution for these situations is to use a junction, or mapping table. `Werknemer` should contain information about crewmen, `Jobfunctie` about job descriptions, and you need a third table to assign crewmen jobs:

```
CREATE TABLE Werknemer (
    personeelsnummer INT(4) NOT NULL,
    voornaam VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    achternaam VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    adres VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    telefoon VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (personeelsnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Jobfunctie (
    jobnumber INT(4) NOT NULL
    jobfunctie VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    salaris_in_euro INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (jobnumber)
);

-- The new junction table
CREATE TABLE Werknemer_Jobfunctie (
    personeelsnummer INT(4) NOT NULL,
    jobnumber INT(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (personeelsnummer, jobnumber),
    FOREIGN KEY (personeelsnummer) references Werknemer (personeelsnummer),
    FOREIGN KEY (jobnumber) references Jobfunctie (jobnumber),
)

-- Insert crewmen
INSERT INTO Werknemer VALUES
(0100, 'firstname', 'lastname', 'adress', 'telephone');
INSERT INTO Werknemer VALUES
(0101, 'firstname2', 'lastname2', 'adress', 'telephone');

-- Insert a job description
INSERT INTO Jobfunctie VALUES
(1, 'Arbeider', 1500);

-- Assign this job to both crewmen
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Jobfunctie VALUES
(0100, 1);
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Jobfunctie VALUES
(0101, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Change your Jobfunctie table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobfunctie (
 jobfunctienummer int(4) not NULL,
 jobfunctie varchar(15) not NULL,
 salaris_in_euro int(10) not NULL,
 personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
 foreign key(personeelsnummer) references Werknemer(personeelsnummer),
 primary key(jobfunctienummer)
);
```

And use inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO Jobfunctie values
('1', 'Arbeider', 1500, 0100);
INSERT INTO Jobfunctie values
('2', 'Arbeider', 1500, 0101);
```